# How do I update application on Cloud Foundry without restarting?

Tags: cloud-foundry

Is it possible to deploy a latest version of my project into CF without restarting the application ? Perhaps something like session draining ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly not right not right now...  What I would suggest is doing a zero down time deployment with Cloud Foundry.  Check out some of the docs at http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/blue-green.html.  The basic premise is to deploy a new version of the app and let both be running at the same time and then move traffic over to the new app.